# Drop / Deploy binaries in TFS repository with VNext build definition

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, tfs, msbuild, azure-devops

In Visual Studio Online (aka Team Services, aka Team Foundation Services) I had some XAML definitions which build and **deploy in the TFS repository** by setting the **Staging location** with:

```
Copy build output to the following drop folder:
    $/{reposotiory}/Drops
```

Now, after creating the new vNext build definitions, I'm unable to reproduce this behavior.

I've created an artifact (server type) as suggested here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/publish-build-artifacts  but it's only accessible through website (in the **Artifact** tab): [image: Artifact tab in visualstudio.com]

Others Stackoverflow questions refer to deploy in a external server by using a UNC path like:

- [TFS 2015 Publish Build Artifacts in one directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852472/tfs-2015-publish-build-artifacts-in-one-directory)
- [TFS Build vNext - copy all assemblies to one folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815713/tfs-build-vnext-copy-all-assemblies-to-one-folder)

Is it possible to drop binaries in the repository? Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the file in local repository first (UNC path, create a share folder) then check in the drop to remote repository. If you want to do that within the build process, just create a cmd/batch file with the [`tf checkin`](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/checkin-command) command.

We don't recommend to do that, as TFS repo is for source control, the binaries files don't need to add in source control. So, with the UNC path or FTP to store the drop file would be a better practice.

[image]

Comment: I don't have my own TFS server, I'm using Visual Studio Online (https://{mycompany}.visualstudio.com/) as repository and build server. As I read in the documentation the Artifact Type file share is not possible to be use in Visual Studio Online. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Alex  The file share is also available for VSTS, you can deploy [private Windows agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows) for building and make sure the agent services account has the permission to access the UNC path.

Comment: Please also answer my question problem in below post https://stackoverflow.com/q/63059180/10846390