# TFS 2015 build Output Location : Single folder option

Tags: build, asp.net-core, tfs-2015

When defining a build in visual studio, there is an option to set the output location of the build to be placed in a single folder as shown here, or into individual folders per project.
[image: Image of option in Visual studio]

I am trying to convert a build into the new vNext build system on **TFS 2015** using the visual studios build step.
For most things it is relativly simple to duplicate the settings, but there doesn't seem to be anyway to set this option, the result of which is as if this was set to 'PerProject' in **XAML** based build definitions.

The old build definition has scripts that are based around the fact that the binaries are all output to a single directory, so this is causing an issue. Obviously I can change the scripts to point to each individual projects build directory, but this is obviously fragile as, for example, changing the build configuration from **Debug** to **Release** changes this location.  Again this is fixable by using environment variables, but I was wondering if there was a way that I have missed to set the build up so that it acts the same way as it did when the old option was set to 'single folder' to avoid having to set all that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are no simple settings can achieve what you need in vNext build for now.

If you only have little projects. You can add several steps to copy the assemblies (One step for one project) and specify the copy root in the step. Details you can refer this question:[Copy one file in target directory on deploy from visual studio team services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587282/copy-one-file-in-target-directory-on-deploy-from-visual-studio-online/34603346#34603346)

If you have a large number of projects. You may have to manually write PowerShell scripts and add it in the build definition to copy these files.