# TFS 2015 VNext Copy Files task without copying folders

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Using the copy task to copy some msi files to the drop location.  The msis are in corresponding bin/debug/release folders.  When I use the copy files task it copies the entire folder structure (bin/debug/...msi) to the target location.  I just want it to copy the files to the target location.  Is that possible?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this as one step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved. However, you need to **specify the copy root** if you want to copy files only without folder structure. You can use `$(Build.StagingDirectory)` as a target for this. Afterwards use the **Publish task** with `$(Build.StagingDirectory)` as copy root and publish everything from this root to the drop.

Detail step and screenshot please take a look at the answer from *Eddie* in this question: [Copy one file in target directory on deploy from visual studio team services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587282/copy-one-file-in-target-directory-on-deploy-from-visual-studio-online)