# Copy app.publish folder in VSTS Build/Release

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, clickonce, azure-devops, tfsbuild

Similar to the question here: [Copy one file in target directory on deploy from visual studio team services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587282/copy-one-file-in-target-directory-on-deploy-from-visual-studio-online), I am trying to copy the contents of the app.publish directory of a ClickOnce application via VSTS build/release.

**This is the Copy Publish Artifact step of the Build**
[image: Copy Publish Artifact Step]

This obviously outputs everything in the bin folder to the drop folder on the server share.

**This is the Copy Files step of the Release**
[image: Copy Files Step]

This copies only the files in the app.publish folder but it builds out the entire hierarchy to the folder app.publish folder; however, it builds out the full folder structure. i.e. bin\Release\app.publish or bin\Debug\app.publish.

I like the idea of being able to publish and store different configurations (debug/release) but I don't like that I'm having to specify the InstallUrl in the msbuild arguments in order to pick up debug/release in the folder path. Even if I didn't try to maintain multiple configurations, the configuration would still be in the path.

So my question is: Is there a way to use the copy files task to just copy the app.publish folder and/or the contents to another location, without it creating the full hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the copy root in Source Folder of Copy Files, in your example, the copy root should be like:

**Source Folder:** `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(Build.DefinitionName)\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\`

**Contents:** `**\app.publish\**`

In this way, you should only have app.publish in your Target Folder.

Comment: The $(BuildConfiguration) variable is not available in the RELEASE Copy Files step without manually creating it. However, I wanted for the release definition to pull from whatever the build configuration was of the build that is associated with the release definition.

Comment: How about use this step in Build definition and drop the app.publish folder with other outputs together.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the "Copy Root" of "Copy Publish Artifacts" step in your build definition to the path of build configuration folder and "Content" to "**".

For example, if the path of your build output is:

> C:\a\1\s\SolutionFolder\ProjectFolder\bin\Relase\app.publish...

You can set the Copy Root to:

> $(build.sourcesdirectory)\SolutionFolder\ProjectFolder\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)

And Content set to:

> **