# TFS publish build artifacts to share with custom path

Tags: tfsbuild, publish, tfs-2015

Is it possible to publish build artifacts with paths other than original?

I have built folders with all necessary files to publish:

- `SolutionName\Project1\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)`
- `SolutionName\Project2\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)`

I want to get:

- `\\share\$(Build.BuildNumber)\$(BuildConfiguration)/Project1`
  `\\share\$(Build.BuildNumber)\$(BuildConfiguration)/Project2`

In Publish build artifacts step I specified

- Copy root SolutionName Content `**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\*`
- Artifact Name `$(Build.BuildNumber)`
- Path `\\share`

And get

- `\\share\$(Build.BuildNumber)\Project1\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\...`
- `\\share\$(Build.BuildNumber)\Project2\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\...`

Comment: I have created a test and updated my reply with detail steps, arguments to achieve this. You could follow it or change them based on your needs. Please kindly review it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Copy File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587282/copy-one-file-in-target-directory-on-deploy-from-visual-studio-team-services/34603346#34603346) task .In this task you could be able to the original directory structure and publish Build Artifacts through `$(Build.StagingDirectory)`.

See this question for details: [Copy one file in target directory on deploy from visual studio team services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587282/copy-one-file-in-target-directory-on-deploy-from-visual-studio-online/34603346#34603346)

---

**Update**

[image]

In your situation, the arguments should be(could change them based on your needs) :

***Two copy files task for each project:***

- Source Folder: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\SolutionName\ProjectName\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)`
- Contents: `**\*`
- Target Folder:
  `$(Build.StagingDirectory)\$(Build.BuildNumber)\$(BuildConfiguration)\projectX`

***One  Copy and Publish Build Artifacts***

- Mostly the same with my screenshot above, **Artifact Type** should be
  File share and Path `\\share`

Finally, you will get the result  as below:
[image]

Comment: But I have only `Windows Machine File Copy` no `Copy File` task

Comment: @SerG I'm afraid your TFS2015 version is  lower than **TFS2015 update3**. This task is only aviable with TFS 2015 Update 3 and later. You may have to update your TFS2015 version to use it.