# TFS 2017 Build Copy Files without folder structure?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

In my TFS 2017 build definition, I am trying to copy a folder with a specific name (Package) towards my Artifacts directory. I am only interested in the specific folder itself, not in it's parent folders.

Can someone enlighten me on how I should make this work?

Current configuration for the Copy Files task:
Source: $(agent.builddirectory)
Contents: **\Package***
Target Folder: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\MyArtifact

This results in the following folderstructure while my only interest is the Package folder:
\MyArtifact\folderX\s\folderY\folderZ\folderA\Package

Answer (score 10):

With *TFS2017update1* and above, *VSTS*, you could simply check **Flatten Folders** under Advanced option in [Copy Files Task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files). The easiest solution for now.

[image]

> This will flatten the folder structure and copy all files into the
>   specified target folder.

Not sure if you are working on 2017 release version, and there is no *Flatten Folders* option. You need to **specify the copy root** if you want to copy files only without folder structure. You can use `$(Build.StagingDirectory)` as a target for this. Afterwards use the **Publish task** with `$(Build.StagingDirectory)` as copy root and publish everything from this root to the drop.

Detail step and screenshot please take a look at the answer from *Eddie* in this question: [Copy one file in target directory on deploy from visual studio team services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587282/copy-one-file-in-target-directory-on-deploy-from-visual-studio-online)

Comment: Thanks for your advice Patrick. I do have the update 1 but I don't want to flatten the folders as my 'Package' folder contains the output of a WCF project: some .svc's in the top level and a bin folder with dll's. I would like to preserve to keep this structure...

Comment: @BenThaens If so you could use the option 2, just copy the files some with structure and some without structure to a medium path such as  `Build.StagingDirectory` instead of directly using  `builddirectory`

Answer (score 1):

If the relative path to "package" does not change, you can specify the detailed path in "Source" to achieve the feature you want.

For example, configure the Copy Files Task:

Source Folder to: `$(agent.builddirectory)\folderY\folderZ\folderA\Package`

Contents to: `**`

Target Folder to: `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\MyArtifact\Package`

You will get the folder structure you want.

Answer (score 1):

While all answers were correct in some way, it was not what I intended to achieve.
I ended up creating my own PowerShell script to copy the package folder and it's contents to the Staging Directory:

```
$BasePath = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName("$(SolutionPath)")
$Search = "PackageTmp"
$Destination = "$(Build.StagingDirectory)"

Get-ChildItem -Path $BasePath -Filter $Search -Directory -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path $Destination $(ArtifactName)} -Recurse -Force
```