# How to make VSTS Build copy files to the output directory with no sub-directories?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I an ASP.NET Core application I need to copy some fonts to the output directory. In my project I store these fonts in the directory ProjectFolder/Assets.

In the properties of each font I have set CopyToOutputDirectory to Always.

When Visual Studio build the project, the files are copied to the same directory where project.exe is built. This is the behavior I expect.

But when I build the project using VSTS, the files are copied to a sub-directory named Assets, this is one level below than the exe.

How can I make VSTS copy the files to the same folder than the exe (as Visual Studio does).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you building the project in VSTS? Can you share a screenshot of your build definition? Where do you notice this "the files are copied to a sub-directory named Assets"? Is this in the artifacts of your build?

Comment: Add a "Copy Files to" step before you publish the files in the build pipeline. You can input the source and target directory. This may be a workarround but would do what you want. You can input the assets folder as source and copy them back into the main folder.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I will try this in the weekend and I’ll let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With *TFS2017update1* and above, *VSTS*, you could simply check **Flatten Folders** under Advanced option in [Copy Files Task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files). The easiest solution for now.

*This option in "Advanced" section of "Copy Files" step of your build definition.*

[image]

> This will flatten the folder structure and copy all files into the
>   specified target folder.

If this do not meet your requirement, you could try to use copy files step,take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34603346/5391065).